# Referencing xsds on classpath when using Spring beans to call xsl

Tags: java, spring, xsd, xslt-1.0

So I currently am working on a project that uses Spring to inject a schema location for the xsd when calling an xsl, something like:

```
<bean id="transformer" class="com.mypackage.Transformer">
    <property name="xsl" value="sample.xsl" />                  
    <property name="params">
        <map>
            <entry key="schemaLocation" value-ref="schema" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="schema" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="http://www.sample.com/schema/sampleSchema.xsd" />
</bean>
```

This works fine when you use a url as the schema location, but say for example you want to refer to a schema that is brought in on the classpath as a maven dependency. I've found that using something like 'classpath:sampleSchema.xsd' doesn't work. I would've thought this kind of behaviour was fairly common, is there an accepted workaround to this? Create a custom class that looks up the schema on the classpath and returns its path as a string?

Answer (score 0):

OK so I thought I would share how I fixed this.

Two spring beans:

```
<bean id="schema" factory-method="getSchemaLocation" factory-bean="schemaFinder" /> 

<bean id="schemaFinder" class="com.mypackage.SchemaFinder">
    <constructor-arg value="NAME_OF_SCHEMA" />
</bean>
```

And a class:

```
public class SchemaFinder
{
private String schemaLocation;

public SchemaFinder(String schemaName) throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        URL absoluteSchemaUrl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(schemaName);
        setSchemaLocation(absoluteSchemaUrl.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //whatever you want here
    }
}

public void setSchemaLocation(String schemaLocation)
{
    this.schemaLocation = schemaLocation;
}

public String getSchemaLocation()
{
    return this.schemaLocation;
}
}
```

Quite easy when you think about it...